# Django Admin - Adding images to form raises an error

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hello there I want to add images to a form from my admin panel with Django. I've created the field like so:

`photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/')`

but I get the following error:

`no such column: blog_post.company Request Method:  GET error: 500 151197`

Comment: You should make and run migrations, so `manage.py makemigrations` and then `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: The error has by the way not directly something to do with adding the `photo` field to the model.